# UDP server app on Linux can't receive packets from more than 150 clients

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I've written a UDP C++ server app on Linux and am now load testing it to see how many clients it can handle.  I find that it peaks at about 150 simultaneous clients sending packets at a rate of 2-4 per second.

Clients added after that will cause some other clients' packets to be dropped.

The server itself is not stressed, using less than 10% of the CPU and memory.  The network is not stressed at all either, at about 15K bytes/second.  The packets are arriving at the server (which uses one UDP socket for both read and write) at about 200 packets/second.  The server threads themselves still sleep for short periods at this load level.

**Question**:
Any ideas on what is the bottleneck here?  CPU, network and server code itself all seem to be unstressed.  Will the OS be unable to handle this # of UDP packets?

The hardware is very low power - a single core Pentium equivalent at 1.5 MHz. The NIC is 100M bits/second.  I'm running Ubuntu 11.1.

This article might be related: [Upper limit to UDP performance on windows server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544296/upper-limit-to-udp-performance-on-windows-server-2008)

*Update*:
The server sets up a UDP socket, then creates 3 threads and 2 queues.  The first thread blocks on socket read and looks like:

```
while (1)
{
    recvfrom(this->socket, readBuf, BUFSIZE, 0, (sockaddr *)&address, &addressLen);
    pushBack(this->inputQueue, message);
}
```

The second thread sleeps on the inputQueue.  It wakes up when a condition is signaled and processes messages.  It sends processed messages to an outputQueue:

```
while (1)
{
    sleepOnQ(this->inputQueue);
    popFront(this->inputQueue);
    processMessage();
    pushBack(this->outputQueue, message);
}
```

The 3rd thread sleeps on the outputQueue and sends messages out the UDP socket to the destination.  Note, it's the same socket that's used for reading.

```
while (1)
{
    sleepOnQ(this->outputQueue);
    popFront(this->outputQueue);
    processMessage();
    sendto(this->socket, message, ... );
}
```

The amount of processing per client and message is small.  As I mentioned when the server is handling 200 messages/second, it's using about 10% of a really wimpy CPU.

Here are some of the kernel parameters on the system:

```
net.core.wmem_max = 114688
net.core.rmem_max = 114688
net.core.wmem_default = 114688
net.core.rmem_default = 114688
```

**More info on data synchronization**

The answers so far have made me think two things are going on:

1. the OS read buffer is filling up.  But with low CPU this shouldn't happen
2. But #1 can happen if the threads are waiting for other events and because of that don't read the socket quickly enough.

Logging could be an issue, I'll try turning it off and report results.  However, probably more important is the contention for the queues between threads.  Since CPU is low, maybe the threads spend a lot of time waiting for access to the queues.

In the first iteration of this server I tried to be tricky about locking data.  The server was very fast but crashed when it got to 800 packets/second.  The current version locks the entire queue.  Maybe I need a better way to synchronize the threads.

**Question answered**

The information I got here was very helpful.  The problem was a bonehead error with the test client, but doing the investigation helped me eliminate the cause suggested here.

FYI here are my results.  Once I fixed the problem with the client the server accepted about 800 packets/second with 70% CPU utilization.  I had increased the OS read/write buffer to 12MB from 128K.  I didn't test whether read buffer was filled.  I doubt the OS read buffer was an issue because at top speed the server read thread was still blocking on read for short periods every 10th or 20th read.

800 packets/second is still too slow, so I removed logging from the server.  This made a huge difference.  Server was able to receive 2900 messages/second from 1400+ clients at 70% cpu util.

I also did some testing with whether the read thread was waiting for the lock.  Even at top speed I found it never had to wait more than 1 ms, so it wasn't a factor at 2900 messages/second.  Perhaps it will be on a faster CPU.

At this point the server is CPU bound and to find the next bottleneck I'll need to get on a more powerful CPU.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is your server designed? How do you handle each client? Are you spinning up multiple threads or is it a single thread? If it's a single thread, how much processing are you doing for each packet? How big is your UDP receive buffer at the OS level? It's hard to answer this without more details of your server design.

Comment: It's essential to know more about your program - code would be nice :)  But also check your tunable kernel parameters.  For example: http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/7001/udp-drops-on-linux

Comment: Thanks for responses, I've updated the question with an outline of the code.  I don't know enough about kernel parameters to tell you.  I'll research it a bit and update the question.  Maybe I should ask this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the lossage is that the UDP socket's incoming-packets buffer fills up before your first thread can empty it; any incoming UDP packets that are received while the buffer is already full will be dropped.

The most likely reason that the first thread can't empty the buffer fast enough to keep it from filling up is that something else is holding it off of the CPU for too long... since it sounds like you are running on a single-core CPU, this is likely the case.  You might want to try setting your second and third threads to a lower priority (so that the first thread will get first dibs on the CPU whenever there is contention) and see if that helps.  If that still isn't good enough, you might set your process to SCHED_RR 'real time' priority, to make sure that any other processes running in the OS don't keep your first thread away from the CPU.  (You can still run your other threads at lower priority, of course, since it doesn't matter so much exactly when they execute).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I'll try these and update the question.  I've updated the question with some more info about what's probably keeping the threads waiting.

Comment: I wanted to +2 on each answer but I don't have enough rep yet

Answer (score 1):

If an incoming UDP datagram does not fit to UDP input buffer (usually buffer is full), then kernel will discard it.

If the buffer is full when the packet rate is only 200/s and CPU load low, then your program wastes time for waiting something else (end of sleep, some resource, etc..) than new packets.

Double check your code. And try to get rid of all `sleep`, `nanosleep` and similar sleeping functions.

If you print lot of (debug) ouputs to serial console, it may start blocking your program, because serial ports are not so fast. Try to eliminate this kind of bottlenecks also.

Comment: excellent, thanks for the suggestions.  I'm going to try increasing the read buffer.  There are no sleeps but the thread will block waiting for a condition var when there's no work.

Comment: I wanted to +2 on each answer but I don't have enough rep yet